# How to restrict values entered in a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, validation, user-interface, user-input, textfield

What is the idiomatic way to limit input in a Flutter `TextField` only to these values which match the regexp `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)$`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `inputFormatters`

```
return TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)$)),
  ],
);
```

I hope this helps.